# Как спарсить этот текст в классы или структуры?

Tags: javascript, c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть кусок страницы, с функцией js:

```
rm_h.init([
    ['auto/00/an','http://e1.example.ru/','ima/v1ch1/Credits.jpg',500,726],
    ['auto/00/an','http://hh.example.ru/','ima/v1ch1/_Anima_v01inside-front.jpg',428,1100]],
    0, false);
```

не могу собрать никак паттерн для Regex, чтобы получить хотя бы строчки

```
['auto/00/an','http://e1.example.ru/','ima/v1ch1/Credits.jpg',500,726]
```

и

```
['auto/00/an','http://hh.example.ru/','ima/v1ch1/_Anima_v01inside-front.jpg',428,1100]
```

А лучше сразу по элементам этих строчек.

Или js можно как то иначе загрузить удобно в c#?

Comment: тут проще всего вызвать у строки `Substring` между `IndexOf('[')` и `LastIndexOf(']')`. 
из-за запятых между [ и ] и между параметрами, паттерн `Regex` будет сложным. если есть универсальный Regex, который может выделить все параметры, напишите ответ [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474247)

Comment: Как раз таки Regex тут лучше, чем substring с индексами. Другое дело, что json оказывается парсится хорошими либами, ниже хороший совет дали. А вам я помочь не могу, не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> json можно загрузить в c#?

C nuget.org скачайте пакет Newtonsoft.Json

к своему проекту подключите сборку Newtonsoft.Json.dll

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
// ...    
var o = JToken.Parse("[['auto/00/an',500,726],['auto/00/an',28,1100]]");
o[1][1].ToString()         //> 28
```

Comment: Спасибо за JToken.Parse, то что нужно.