# Как в C# получить значение параметра javascript функции?

Tags: javascript, c#, парсер

В javascript коде есть вызовы функции с несколькими параметрами. 
В программе на C# надо прочесть один из параметров. 
Например в javascript-коде есть следующие вызовы функции:

```
app.log("регулярное выражение", /\w+\d+/gi, Date.now());
app.log({'id':1, 'value':123});
app.log("json array", [[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]);
```

в C# надо прочесть javascript-код, найти вызовы функции, и получить соответственно:

```
"/\w+\d+/gi"
"{'id':1, 'value':123}"
"[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]"
```

Для этого можно использовать Regex, но регулярные выражения получатся достаточно сложными.
Возможно, что есть другой способ, без использования регулярных выражений?

Comment: Не вполне понял — а для чего вам регулярка? Какая ваша реальная задача? Что по сути, в текстовом виде находится в логе? (Да, я не знаю JS.)

Comment: мне нужен мини-парсер javascript, который из javascript-кода может извлекать значения, указанные в вызовах функций.

Comment: А, вот это **и есть** строки? `"app.log("регулярное выражение", /\w+\d+/gi, Date.now());"`?

Comment: _"Что по сути, в текстовом виде находится в логе?"_ -- в текстовом файле находятся примерно такие строки: app.log("регулярное выражение", /\w+\d+/gi, Date.now());

Comment: Хм. Бррр. Хорошо. Парсить джаваскрипт лучше, разумеется парсером джаваскрипта. Тогда вопрос: а как они вообще туда попали? Почему в таком ужасном виде?

Comment: Не обманывайте себя. Не бывает мини-парсера, бывает просто полновесный парсер. Если вам нужно понять, что `/\w+\d+/gi` — это регулярка, а `{'id':1, 'value':123}` — это литерал объекта, то вам нужен полный, без дураков, парсер JS.

Comment: Или вы пытаетесь на C# распарсить **программу** на js? Гиблое дело, забейте.

Comment: _"А, вот это и есть строки?"_ -- да. исправил текст вопроса.

Comment: @VladD, почему это _на C# распарсить программу на js гиблое дело_?

Comment: @Grundy: Парсер — большая и сложная штука, не один день работы. Скорее всего, намного проще выполнить код на js интерпретатором js, и не изобретать атомную бомбу для уничтожения двух тараканов.

Comment: @VladD _"вы пытаетесь на C# распарсить программу на js?"_ -- да, надо найти только вызовы функции и прочесть значения определенных параметров.

Comment: @Stack: Я бы делал не так. Выцарапываеть данные из исходников на другом языке — неправильный подход. Скормите код интерпретатору JS, укажите свой объект `app`, и дело с концом.

Comment: @Stack: Вы представляете, как вы будете искать все вызовы app.log в языке, в котором есть `eval`? Задача невыполнима.

Comment: @VladD _"намного проще выполнить код на js интерпретатором js"_ --  весь код выполнять не надо, да и не вполне невозможно. потому что есть не все файлы проекта.

Comment: @VladD, если сильно ограничить входные данные, и четкий формат строк и параметров, например, строки могут быть только: `app.log(...);` где `...` - может быть только каких-то заранее заданных форматов, то задача весьма сильно упрощается

Comment: @VladD, так сказать, вопрос только во входных данных :)

Comment: А что вы хотите делать с кодом типа такого: `function apply(arg) { app.log(arg); } apply({ 'id' : 1 }); eval("apply(0)"); apply(apply);`

Comment: @Grundy: Практически, попробуйте, имея исходник программы на C#, выдать все строки, которые эта программа выводит на консоль. Не компилируя программу и не запуская. Текст программы — больше, чем данные.

Comment: @VladD, вот поэтому я и сказал про ограничение: _например, строки могут быть только: app.log(...);_ ;-D То есть не цельная программа, а просто список строк как приведено в посте

Comment: @VladD, для этих целей есть статические анализаторы кода, которые в принципе могут с этим справится :-) но да, это не один день, и даже не два :-D

Comment: Внутри объекта может быть функция. Внутри функции — целый мир.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33093/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladD _"что вы хотите делать с кодом типа такого: function apply(arg) ...."_ -- ничего, даже если бы и был. но к счастью такого в коде нет.

Comment: @Grundy: Стат. анализаторы находят простые, очевидные случаи. Они не могут справится с таким в общем случае из-за halting theorem.

Comment: _"для этих целей есть статические анализаторы кода"_ -- они проверяют код, а мне надо только значения параметров получить.

Comment: @Stack, без анализа кода, получить значение невозможно :-)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33104/discussion-on-question-by-stack---c----javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Передать данные с джаваскрипт в сишарп, например:

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/708709/Pass-javascript-variables-value-to-Csharp-code-beh#answer2

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122357/how-should-data-be-passed-between-client-side-javascript-and-c-code-behind-an-a

Для вылова значений можно использовать методы строки, например:
[substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring), [split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split), [between-before-after](http://www.dotnetperls.com/between-before-after)

Comment: спасибо, но это не совсем то, что надо. виноват, текст вопроса был не вполне понятным. уже исправил.